# Authentication Manager is NoOpAuthenticationManager when method security operation. Why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I set up Spring Security with a custom Authentication Provider.

Custom authentication works normally if method security (such as @Secured) is not set.
But when I set up Method Security, `AuthenticationServiceException` occurs.
[image]

I tried debugging.
`authenticationManager.authenticate` was called once more upon entering a controller with method security enabled. However, the authentication manager was empty(=NoOpAuthenticationManager) at this time.

I called the API below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
class TestController
```

Comment: Your configuration is wrong ... right there ... where we **can't see it**.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I had set the setting as below.

```
spring:
  main:
    lazy-initialization: true
```

I think the cause was an lazy injection.